# Issues changing button text JavaScript with .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a project that requires mapping a series of random values to button titles, and I am having issues with assigning the titles after random generation. Below is my HTML and JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javaFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Matching Game</h1>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <button class="gameBtn" id="b00"></button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b01">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b02">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b03">NO SHOW</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b10">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b11">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b12">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b13">NO SHOW</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b20">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b21">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b22">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b23">NO SHOW</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b30">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b31">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b32">NO SHOW</button></td>
      <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b33">NO SHOW</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var startingList = ["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8"];
var gameList = [];

function onLoad() {
  var i;

  for (i = startingList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    gameList.push(startingList[rndNum]);
    startingList.splice(rndNum, 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("b00").innerHTML = gameList[0];
}
window.onload = onLoad();
alert(gameList);
```

So above, I have most of the button assignments commented out to focus on getting the first part right. The random generation works, as when I make it display the alert message it shows the random array properly. However when I include the button assignment it does not process the alert (I believe this is because the code kicks up an error and thus doesn't get to that point.

Also above, I pulled the button out to see if the table was causing the issues but it didn't work either way. It is supposed to be in the first part of the table.

I checked through other answers and followed the same format for labeling a button, and double checked the file names to make sure everything was right. Just a bit lost here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To start with, `window.onload = onLoad();` change to `window.onload = onLoad;`

Comment: You've got to be kidding...That fixed it. Been spending 20 min trying to figure out what assignment syntax I did wrong. Thanks a lot! The loading of the array in alert not longer functions, but that was just a test case, all the buttons work great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var startingList = ["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8"];
var gameList = [];

function int_rnd(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function onLoad() {
  for (var key in startingList) {
    var rndNum = int_rnd(key, startingList.length - 1);
    gameList.push(startingList[rndNum]);
    startingList.splice(rndNum, 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("b00").innerHTML = gameList[0];
}
window.onload = onLoad;
```

```html
<h1>Matching Game</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<button class="gameBtn" id="b00"></button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b01">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b02">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b03">NO SHOW</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b10">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b11">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b12">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b13">NO SHOW</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b20">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b21">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b22">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b23">NO SHOW</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b30">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b31">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b32">NO SHOW</button></td>
    <td><button class="gameBtn" id="b33">NO SHOW</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```